# ruby unit testing at_start not found

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, jruby

I am using test-unit-2.5.5 with ruby 1.9.3. In http://test-unit.rubyforge.org/test-unit/en/Test/Unit.html#at_start-class_method there is a method called at_start as part of the ruby test::unit module from version 2.5.2. I tried to use it from the examples on the page like so:

```
class TestAOS < Test::Unit::TestCase
  Test::Unit.at_start do
    puts "start"
  end
  Test::Unit.at_exit do
    puts "Exit!"
  end
```

But when I run my test I get the following:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `at_start' for Test::Unit:Module
  TestAOS at unit/TestAOS.rb:8
   (root) at unit/TestAOS.rb:7
```

Do I need to do anything first before this method can be used? I'm new to ruby

When I comment out the at_start bloack and run the test I get a different error for at_exit:

```
NoMethodError: private method `at_exit' called for Test::Unit:Module
  TestAOS at unit/TestAOS.rb:12
   (root) at unit/TestAOS.rb:7
```

A

Answer (score 0):

In the example provided by your link the

```
Test::Unit.at_start do
  puts "start"
end
```

is called outside of test class. You are calling it from inside of your test class. Just move it outside of your `TestAOS`

Comment: I did and got the same issue